# Is it possible to use Selenium to automate the testing of voice-controlled applications or devices, like smart speakers or virtual assistants

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm exploring the possibility of automating the testing of voice-controlled applications, such as smart speakers and virtual assistants, using Selenium. I'm looking for guidance on how to set up a test automation environment that can interact with these voice-driven interfaces, record and analyze voice responses, and perform automated tests. Any insights, resources, or best practices for this unique testing challenge would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried using standard Selenium WebDriver methods to interact with the web interface of the voice-controlled application, but I'm struggling to simulate voice commands and capture responses effectively.

I was expecting to find a solution or best practices for automating the testing of voice-controlled applications using Selenium, or suggestions on alternative tools or approaches that are better suited for this specific task.

Comment: What language would you like to use with Selenium?

Comment: Java as a programming language